# Alternative for deprecated new Double(double)

Tags: java, wrapper, deprecated

I'm following a book by Walter Savitch called Absolute Java. A sample program in it contains the following lines:

```
Double[] d = new Double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    d[i] = new Double(d.length - i);
```

And I got the following warning message:

> warning: [deprecation] Double(double) in Double has been deprecated

I believe that the warning message is telling me to replace the use of constructors since it is already deprecated, so what should I replace it with?

Comment: Your question is answered in the Javadoc.

Comment: The question is asked very well, but it is answered by simply looking up the Javadoc. This is something that is generally expected before posting at SO. So I have to give a downvote for lack of research. Please see [ask], thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Explanation

You should replace it with:

```
d[i] = Double.valueOf(d.length - i);
```

From its [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#%3Cinit%3E(double)):

> **Deprecated**.
>
> It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory `valueOf(double)` is generally a better choice, as it is likely to **yield significantly better space and time performance**.

In general, `valueOf` is not forced to always return a **new** instance. It can utilize an internal cache and re-use values created before already, which makes it faster. For example if you create hundreds of `1.0`.

---

### Note

Is there a specific reason you are using a `Double[]` in the first place? If not, go for `double[]` instead. The primitives are much faster and have less memory overhead, compared to their object wrapper.

Then your code is just:

```
double[] d = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    d[i] = d.length - i;
```

---

By the way, you should prefer to never omitt the curly braces. Even if your loop is just one line. This is a very common source for bugs that are hard to find.

Also, your variable naming is not very good. What is `d`? Try to give it a name that reflects what it actually means. Like `ages` if it stores person ages, for example. If you do not have something specific, maybe use `values`. That is already better than just `d`. Especially since it is plural, so it is clear that it is an array of multiple values.

```
double[] values = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i] = values.length - i;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a specific reason for using Double since the author was trying to demonstrate a program that will sort any kind of data types using the Comparable interface which is implemented by the class Double.

Comment: Fair enough, then stick to `Double[]` :)

Comment: @Zabuza but you could use `d[i] = (double) (d.length - i);`, which implicitly uses `valueOf` via autoboxing.

Answer (score 1):

From Java 9 constructor(s) method(s) was [Deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#Double-double-)

> Deprecated. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory **`valueOf(double)` is generally a better choice**, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.
>   Constructs a newly allocated Double object that represents the primitive double argument.

So replace with:

```
Double.valueOf(d.length - i)
```